# yii2 rest api create custom response body

Tags: rest, yii2

Please help newbie, 
how can a get response like that, i extends from ActiveController,
actionIndex it is prepareDataProvider that returns SearchModel.

```
 {
   "success": true,
   "result": {
     "list": [
       {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "List title"
         "list":[]
       }
     }
    ]
  }
}

enter code here
```

I use

```
public $serializer = [
    'class' => 'yii\rest\Serializer',
    'collectionEnvelope' => 'list',
];
```

And get

```
enter code here

{
    "list": [
        {
          "id": 12,
          "name": "api list 6 ",
          "list": "6 create "
        },
        {
          "id": 13,
          "name": "api list 10 crt ",
          "list": "10 crt "
      },
  ]
}
```

This is for react.js app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[yii\rest\Serializer](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/78c95b453cce7a0ae3fd09d5ad63ac141462cec4/framework/rest/Serializer.php) is the class responsible of styling data output. In your case you only need to adapt [those lines in source code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/78c95b453cce7a0ae3fd09d5ad63ac141462cec4/framework/rest/Serializer.php#L200-L202) to your need. Create a new class extending the original one and adjust the method output as follow:

```
<?php
namespace app\components;

class Serializer extends \yii\rest\Serializer
{
     /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function serializeDataProvider($dataProvider)
    {
        $output = parent::serializeDataProvider($dataProvider);

        if (!is_array($output)) return $output;

        return [
            'success' => true,
            'result' =>  $output
        ] ;
    }
}
```

Then make your controller using it instead of the original:

```
public $serializer = [
    'class' => 'app\components\Serializer',
    'collectionEnvelope' => 'list',
];
```

That should be enough to get the following output:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "result": {
        "list": [ {...}, {...}, {...} ],
        "_links": {...},
        "_meta": {...}
    }
}
```